# Set default value depending on actual time INFOPATH

Tags: datetime, infopath, dropdownbox

I'm trying to set a default value in a DropDown box depending on the current time. (substring-after(now(), "T"))

To be more specific, I would like my DropDown box to have as default value

- "AM" if the current time is between 06:00:01 and 12:00:00.
- "PM" if the current time is between 12:00:01 and 18:00:00.
- "NIGHT" if the current time is between 18:00:01 and 06:00:00.

I tried with "Rules" and "Set default value" but can't figure out a solution.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

go get the hours and seconds number and put it fields.

A - hours
B - seconds

- A >= 6 and B > 0 OR A =< 12 and B = 0  ---> **AM**
- if A >= 12 and B > 0 OR A =< 18 and B = 0  ---> **PM**
- if A >= 18 and B > 0 OR A =< 6 and B = 0  ---> **NIGHT**

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, I put hours in a field (I don't think it's absolutely necessary but it's more clear for the formula after) then I set the default value for the formula of the DropDown Box as :

```
concat(substring("AM", 1, (field4 < 12) * string-length("AM")), substring("PM", 1, (not(field4 < 12)) * string-length("PM")))
```

field4 is the field when I extract the current hour of the day with that formula:

```
substring-before((substring-after(now(), "T")), ":")
```

You will find usefull tips here for this application:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/11/27/conditional-default-values.aspx